# Duplicated jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When i use file parameter in jenkins job and select some file from network drive location , after clicking "Build" job is run twice. I just tried create "Dummy" job which only takes selected file and copy this particular file into my jenkins workspace. Same result. Job is always duplicated.

When i choose file from local drive , problem doesn't occurs.

Any suggestions ?\
Thanks in advance ...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wojKo.jpg)